# Is there a record of the times the nuclear brief case or its Russian counterpart have ever been actually opened?

Tags: united-states, russia, nuclear-weapons

So, it's a pretty simple question. When, and how many times has the nuclear brief-case or it's Russian counterpart ever been opened *with the intent of use for a nuclear launch*? Are there records of such things? Obviously, they've never been used to completion, but I'd be interested to know if any sitting president or premier has felt it was necessary to do so.

[Inspired by this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34644/does-the-president-of-the-united-states-have-the-ability-to-deploy-nuclear-weapo)

Comment: Downvoter, am I off topic?

Comment: According to [this](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/washington/2005-05-05-nuclear-football_x.htm) article, White House Military Aides have opened theirs. However, the number of times opened by them may not be readily available.

Comment: Do you think this information would be publicly available? I think it is pretty much a common sense.

Comment: Rathony I see no reason to believe it wouldn't be after the fact, at least for the US one. There is a lot more damming information than that that is public.

Comment: Do you mean for any reason or are you discounting, say, occasional updates and auditing that would seem nessecary (to me) for what is essentially a set of documents referencing available options?

Comment: @StarWeaver I've updated the question to make it clear that I'm asking about when it was opened with intent of use to launch.

Comment: it is regularly opened, in order to update the documents it contains or upgrade some equipment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Norwegian Rocket Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_rocket_incident) appears to have prompted the opening of the Russian Federation's briefcase. That Wikipedia article says that was the only such incident, but that seems unlikely to me.